# Отправка JSON через AJAX

Tags: ajax, json

Пытаюсь отправить JSON файл на локальный сервер

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-role=open-session-btn]', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8911/api/1.0/",
        method: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {"jsonrpc" : "2.0",
                "method" : "start",
                "_params" : []
            },  
 });
});
```

На сервер приходит не json, а строка jsonrpc=2.0&method=start.
Как отправить данные, чтобы они пришли в виде json ?

```
{
   "jsonrpc" : "2.0",
   "method" : "start",
   "_params" : []
}
```

На сервере данные принимаются во так:

```
 System.IO.Stream body = request.InputStream;
 System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(body, request.ContentEncoding);
 string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Хм, со стороны фронта все норм вроде. См. бекенд

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте поменять параметр data вот так:

`data: JSON.stringify(data),`

Comment: Посмотрите еще вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693947/how-to-send-json-instead-of-a-query-string-with-ajax)